# Distinguish Button click xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I have four buttons in my xamarin.forms application.Each button click will open a listview in a Popup.I am trying to open same popup page on each button click.I am using messeging centre for returning the listview selected item back to button page. Where I am stuck is how can I distinguish the button click in popup page?Should I use a flag or somethong?

**My Button page**

```
  void Button1_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new AnswerPopup(tranzaction));

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, "AnsData", (value) =>
            {
                string receivedData = value.Myvalue;
                Answer1.Text = receivedData;
            });
        }

        void Button2_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new AnswerPopup(tranzaction));

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, "AnsData", (value) =>
            {
                string receivedData = value.Myvalue;
                Answer2.Text = receivedData;
            });
        }
        void Button3_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new AnswerPopup(tranzaction));

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, "AnsData", (value) =>
            {
                string receivedData = value.Myvalue;
                Answer3.Text = receivedData;
            });
        }
```

**My popup page**

```
   private string selectedItem;     
        private void AnsList_Tapped(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedCategory = e.SelectedItem as Answer;
            if (selectedCategory != null)
                selectedItem = selectedCategory.Text;
            MessagingCenter.Send(new MyMessage() { Myvalue = selectedItem.ToString() }, "AnsData");
            PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

Comment: why don't you send a unique key for each button to AnswerPopup, and in turn have AnswerPopup send that key back via MessagingCenter?

Comment: @Jason bro can you explain?

Comment: @AndroDevil You can create one messaging center for all these buttons and receive buttonId in it and use switch/case for identifying which button was tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you don't need to subscribe multiple times, just do it once per page (in the constructor, typically)

second, add a property to `MyMessage` that will tell you which button as called

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMessage>(this, "AnsData", (value) =>
        {
            string receivedData = value.Myvalue;

            switch (value.Question) {
              case "Q1":
                Answer1.Text = receivedData;
                break;
              case "Q2":
                Answer2.Text = receivedData;
                break;
              case "Q3":
                Answer3.Text = receivedData;
                break;
            }


        });
```

finally, when calling `AnswerPopup`, pass a key for the question (which it will then need to pass back via `MyMessage` when calling `MessagingCenter.Send()`

```
void Button1_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use "Q2", "Q3", etc as appropriate
        PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new AnswerPopup(tranzaction, "Q1"));
    }
```

Comment: Let me check bro

Comment: How to pass the key when calling MessagingCenter.Send()?

Comment: you are already sending MyMessage, just add a property to it that includes the Question ID